# How to remove space only between words and not digits or special characters using Regex?

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching, space

I have a string like this;

```
ab cd 1234567 1234567 ef gh 1234567 1234567 ij kl - - - -
```

I want the output to look like this;

```
abcd 1234567 1234567 efgh 1234567 1234567 ijkl - - - -
```

How to achieve this? Currently I am using the following and it doesn't work.

```
result = result.trim().replaceAll("(\\w)(\\s+)([\\.,])", "");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])", "")` if you want to remove all whitespaces between letters. Or, `replaceAll("(?U)(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "")`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQGYs4/1).

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked - the second one throws this error - java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 3
W/System.err: (?U)(?<=\p{L})\s+(?=\p{L})

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that is Android, you do not need to tell its regex to be Unicode aware, it is already Unicode aware. In Java, you must add `(?U)` so that `\s` could match all Unicode whitespaces.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (and all other answers that turned out helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all whitespaces between ASCII letters you may use

```
result = result.trim().replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])", "");
```

Or, to match any Unicode whitespaces between any Unicode letters, you may use

```
result = result.trim().replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "");
```

Note that in Java, you must prepend the pattern with `(?U)` if you want `\s` to match any Unicode whitespaces (the shorthand character classes are not Unicode-aware by default in Java, they are in Android).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQGYs4/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\\p{L})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location inside a string that is immediately preceded with any Unicode letter
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=\\p{L})` -  a positive lookahead that matches a location inside a string that is immediately followed with any Unicode letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this pattern work for you. `/(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s(?=[a-zA-Z])/m`

Here is a sample code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s(?=[a-zA-Z])";
final String string = "ab cd 1234567 1234567 ef gh 1234567 1234567 ij kl - - - -";
final String subst = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a nice RegEx to do it, but if you want code to do it, I can give you a clever way to get it done.

This is untested, and coded in text here, so you may have to tweak it, but you get the picture.

```
String myString = 'ab cd 1234567 1234567 ef gh 1234567 1234567 ij kl - - - -'
//break it up into array split by space
String[] chunks = myString.split(" ")
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Int x = 0
while (x < chunks.length) 
{ 
    if(isNumeric(chunks[x])){
        //if num add space back
        sb.append(chunk[x]).append(" ")
    }else if(x < chunks.length - 1 && !isNumeric(chunks[x + 1])){
        //if it's string & next value is also a string
        sb.append(chunk[x])
    }else{
        //if it's a string, but next is numeric, we need space
        sb.append(chunk[x]).append(" ")
    }
    x++;
} 

//convert back to string with space between letters removed
String correctedString = builder.toString().trim();
```